# How to call a function from an HTML template using observables?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, observable

I used to call functions from the template but I learned recently that it is not a good idea since it renders time. I tried to assign value to variable and subscribe it to change using setting service observables but it does not work for me.

```
public getMaxUnit(){
return MaxUnits.Dollars;
}
```

```
<div style="display: flex;">
        <table style="width:100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Max</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let maxValue of maxValueTable">
                    <td> {{ maxValue | numberFormatter: getMaxUnit()}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

How can I assign please the value to a variable using .subscribe() method?

Comment: You code does not contain any Observable. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I added the code without observables because it does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use observables in your html page with [async pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).
In your code, your pipe takes an observable parameter.
To achieve this you need to wrap your getMaxUnit with **async pipe**.

[Here is a similar example you can check](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wemjvq?file=src/app/app.component.html) and you can change getDateFormat function to how its date is changing.

```js
public getMaxUnit():Observable<string>{
   return of(MaxUnits.Dollars);
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
        <table style="width:100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Max</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let maxValue of maxValueTable">
                    <td> {{ maxValue | numberFormatter: (getMaxUnit() | async)}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but still calling a function from the template in this case, no?